# Waiting for Subscription to complete

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-material, observable

I have following code

```
this.subscription = this.someService.subscribe((event: FormEvent) => {
    let isConfirmed:boolean;

    this.openDialog();

    const confirmDialogSubscription:Subscription = 
      this.dialogRef.componentInstance.onConfirm.subscribe(() => {
      this.dialogRef.close();
      isConfirmed = true;
    });

    const closeDialogSubscription = 
      this.dialogRef.componentInstance.onClose.subscribe(() => {
      this.dialogRef.close();
      isConfirmed = false;
    });


    //Should be executed after one of these Subscription has fired
    if(isConfirmed){
       //keep on executing
    }
    else{ 
       //stopEvent
       event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
});
```

Currently I have the typical async problem of the code keeps getting executed and going through with the event. I want to wait on the subscriptions.

(Note: I am using Angular Material Dialog and have two Output Event Emitters defined)

EDIT: My main problem is just, that this "someService" is a service of a library I am using. It provides me the possibility to subscribe to events, but it will also do it's stuff once it gets fired. So before my subscription has ended, I need to have called the `event.preventDefault()` or not.

Answer (score 0):

move the expression into a separate function and call it inside the subscription

```
checkCondition(){
      //Should be executed after one of these Subscription has fired
    if(isConfirmed){
       //keep on executing
    }
    else{ 
       //stopEvent
       event.preventDefault();
    }
}


const confirmDialogSubscription:Subscription = 
  this.dialogRef.componentInstance.onConfirm.subscribe(() => {
  this.dialogRef.close();
  isConfirmed = true;
  this.checkCondition()
});

const closeDialogSubscription = 
  this.dialogRef.componentInstance.onClose.subscribe(() => {
  this.dialogRef.close();
  isConfirmed = false;
  this.checkCondition()

});
```

Comment: Couldn't you just `merge` the two observables and then call the function?

Comment: The problem is the code execution. It won't get stopped in your example.

Comment: I updated it. The important thing is my someService.subscribe() function. Because once the code execution steps out of it, I need to now isConfirmed and call event.preventDefault() or not.

Comment: If you need to do stuff before stepping out of the `subscibe` function, then it is easier with this answer provided, ignore my above comment.

Comment: @AgashThamo.  The answer above doesn't work for me. Yes it works inside the confirmDialogSubscription and the closeDialogSubscription, but I have both of these inside another subscription. The Javascript Engine will just continue running the code in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to turn this around into a chain of Observables - avoid subscribing in multiple places and just subscribe once to the whole chain:

```
let evt: FormEvent = null;
this.subscription = this.someService.pipe(
    flatMap((event:FormEvent) => {
        evt = event;
        this.openDialog();
        // Race will emit whichever of the passed observables emits first:
        return race(
            this.dialogRef.componentInstance.onConfirm.pipe(map(() => true)),
            this.dialogRef.componentInstance.onClose.pipe(map(() => false))
        );
    })
).subscribe((confirmed) => {
    if (!confirmed) {
        return evt.preventDefault();
    } else {
       // Call whatever code you wish to continue if confirmed.
    }
});
```

With Observables, it is very rarely desirable to have more than one subscription for a single logical flow - instead, always look to compose a single observable to represent the entire functional flow then subscribe, once, to that.

With regards to the asynchronicity problem, see my comments inline in your code below - the subscriptions will ALWAYS fire later than where you are assessing whether to call preventDefault, and if the event from someService carries on processing if you do not preventDefault within the same stack frame, it will not be possible to avoid that:

```
this.subscription = this.someService.subscribe((event: FormEvent) => {
    let isConfirmed:boolean;

    this.openDialog();

    const confirmDialogSubscription:Subscription = 
      this.dialogRef.componentInstance.onConfirm.subscribe(() => {
      ///// THIS WILL EXECUTE ASYNCHRONOUSLY, SOME TIME LATER
      this.dialogRef.close();
      isConfirmed = true;
    });

    const closeDialogSubscription = 
      this.dialogRef.componentInstance.onClose.subscribe(() => {
      ///// THIS WILL EXECUTE ASYNCHRONOUSLY, SOME TIME LATER
      this.dialogRef.close();
      isConfirmed = false;
    });

    ///// THIS WILL ALWAYS BE EXECUTED BEFORE EITHER OF THE ABOVE
    ///// SUBSCRIPTIONS SO isConfirmed WILL ALWAYS HAVE ITS DEFAULT
    ///// VALUE:    
    //Should be executed after one of these Subscription has fired
    if(isConfirmed){
       //keep on executing
    }
    else{ 
       //stopEvent
       event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
});
```

The only solution to this would be to have a different button to trigger the event, then if the user confirms, manually trigger whatever the event is that you're trying to control (if that's possible).

Comment: I get an Typescript Error, saying the void paramater of flatMap() is not assignable to ObservableInput. I can't return true or false.

Comment: @user5417542 sorry, I think I got my map and flatMap backwards - updated to correct - try that!

Comment: Ok, but this is still not the solution to my problem. Once I am in the subscribe((confirmed)=>{}) function the programm has already continued. See the user clicks a button, a event gets emitted which does something. I want to intercept it and wait for the user to click Confirm in a Dialog. So in your answer following happens: User clicks a button, the event fires and you subscribe to some things and the Dialog opens. But the code doesnt pause, the event still continues at the library im using and gets processed. Once the user clicks "Confirm" in the opened Dialog it's currently already over

Comment: If you have no control over the code in someService, there is no way you can avoid that if it continues and processes whatever you are trying to cancel before the asynchronous operation completes. You cannot get the result of an asynchronous operation synchronously in JavaScript / TypeScript (unlike, say, c# where you can explicitly synchronously wait for an async operation) @user5417542

Comment: But I am able to call "preventDefault" and then it stops. I am currently looking into creating Promises out of the buttonSubscriptions. Shouldnt i then be able to use await?

Comment: await is just syntatic sugar to do the same as an observable.subscribe or promise.then - it doesn't change the actual underlying asynchronous to synchronous. You'll find that if you do toPromise on the observable and await it, the event.preventDefault will be "too late" all the same.

Comment: @user5417542 I've added a commented-version of your code to my answer to try and clarify this

Comment: Ok definitely need to look into that. I also tried. Using preventDefault directly to cancel the event and then inside the confirmButton Subscription unsubscribing the someService.Subscription and calling someService.next(event) to trigger the event again, but this time without my subscription interfering. Somehow this also didnt work even though the timing seems to right.

Comment: @user5417542 can you tell me what the event you're trying to respond to actually is (i.e. what someService actually does)? I might be able to suggest another approach

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177969/discussion-between-mark-hughes-and-user5417542).